# How to get Skype to open on start-up?

Tags: skype, autostart

I want Skype to open automatically on start-up. So I got the instructions... *Start-up Applications* > *Add*. Then I get a window with three fields. In the first I write "Skype".  In the second I cut and paste the code: `/usr/bin/skype` as instructed.  In the third field I write "Internet Telephony".  I then press <kbd>Add…</kbd> and all I get is another box.

The application simply will not load. I have tried every possible permutation of that code, with no result. This has taken months of trying and I still can't get Skype to open on startu-up!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Try `skype` in the second window instead of `/usr/bin/skype`. Can you tell us what the next box says? Can you start skype by typing `skype` in a terminal? Open a terminal by pressing Ctrl+Alt+T. **Please edit your original question with additional information.**